# For loop to calculate factorials

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, for-loop, factorial

Currently I have this set of code and its meant to calculate factorials.

```
int numberInt = int.Parse(factorialNumberTextBox.Text);

for (int i = 1; i < numberInt; i++)
{
  numberInt = numberInt * i;
}

factorialAnswerTextBox.Text = numberInt.ToString();
```

For some reason it doesn't work and i have no clue why. For example i will input 3 and get the answer as -458131456 which seems really strange.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You change the loop condition `numberInt` within the loop. Use another variable.

Comment: you are changing the value of the variable numberInt inside the for loop, and the same varable is used for comparision.

Comment: Also, be aware that using the 32bit `int` you'll only be able to calculate up to 12 factorial. Perhaps consider using the 64bit `long` instead. EDIT: Well, `long` is only good for up to 20 factorial anyway. :) EDIT: Bring on the `BigInteger`!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
int numberInt = int.Parse(factorialNumberTextBox.Text);
int result = numberInt;

for (int i = 1; i < numberInt; i++)
{
    result = result * i;
}

factorialAnswerTextBox.Text = result.ToString();
```

on a side note: this would normally NOT be the correct way to calculate factorials.
You'll need a check on the input before you can begin calculation, in case your starting value is 1 or below, in that case you need to manually return 1.

On another side note: this is also a perfect example of where recursive methods can be useful.

```
int Factorial(int i)
{
    if (i <= 1)
        return 1;
    return i * Factorial(i - 1);
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle the case for 0!, the result of which should be 1.

Comment: it will only works if the numberInt is less then equal to 20, for larger values, integer result overflow will happen.

Comment: I made a version of this today to calculate combinations and tripped over the (obvious?) fact that factorials get very big very fast with relatively small inputs. The simple solution is to use System.Numerics.BigInteger rather than any value type of integer (even UInt64).

Answer (score 24):

A little late to the party:

```
Func<int, int> factorial = n => n == 0 ? 1 : 
    Enumerable.Range(1, n).Aggregate((acc, x) => acc * x);
```

Comment: Nice solution but you should look to catch n = 0 and short circuit to return 1

Comment: over engineering? :-)

Comment: @JorisBrauns: Not really... It's tail recursive, and won't cause a stack overflow if given a high enough number as input. The recursive solution by Wim Ombelets will eventually.

Comment: @ebb - Thanks for sharing.. I like the approach; short and sweet...  In my case, I fed the delegate and int array....  it's not necessary to short-circuit... Total calculated just fine without it.......... Func<int[], int> factorial = n => n.Aggregate((acc, x) => acc * x); total = factorial(intArray);

Comment: It works until 12! )) Can't change to the BigInteger because of Enumerable.Range(1, n)

Comment: Enumerable.Range(1, n)
                .Select(el => (BigInteger)el)
                .Aggregate((accum, x) => accum*x);

Answer (score 4):

You can use this (rather elegant) solution:

```
    Func<int, int> factorial = null; 
    factorial = x => x <= 1 ? 1 : x * factorial(x-1);
    int numberInt = int.Parse(factorialNumberTextBox.Text);
    factorialAnswerTextBox.Text = factorial(numberInt).ToString();
```

Comment: that's not an elegant, but unreadable solution (I would suggest using ternary operator only when case is trivial and easy to understand)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int Factorial(int facno)
{
    int temno = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= facno; i++)
    {
        temno = temno * i;
    }

    return temno;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i am late to the party but here it is

```
    public ulong Factorial(uint numb)
    {
        if (numb <= 1) return 1;
        ulong final = 1;
        for (uint i = 1; i <= numb; i++)
        {
            final *= i;
        }
        return final;
    }
```

Note:
i used un-signed types for better range
as this calculates up to Factorial(65), while normal signed types will give negative values

Answer (score 1):

Trying to make a more bulletproof solution for n factorial. Here is one that guards for overflows, as well as negative and zero values of n. Using a result variable of type long (instead of int) allows for "larger" values to be calculated (for long, you can calculate up to and including n = 20).

This code returns 0 if an overflow occurred, but you can change it to do whatever is more appropriate.

```
    static long nFactorial(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        long result = 1;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                result = checked(result * i); 
            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a factorial method for calculating combinations and tripped over the fact that factorials get very big very fast with relatively small inputs. Here's my solution without using recursion to avoid stack overflow and implemented using `System.Numerics.BigInteger`.

```
static BigInteger factorial(int num) {
    BigInteger result = 1;
    while (num > 1) {
        result *= num--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Obviously, you could also using `BigInteger` for input but my use case was that I was processing `int` values.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it using **For Loop** is:

```
private static int Fact(int num){
  if (num <= 1){
    return 1;
  }
  int result = 0;
  for(int i = num; i > 1; i--){
    --num; 
    result = (result == 0) ? i-- * num : result * i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you put Fact(3), num will have a value of 3. We store it to i then i = 3, the --num will be reduced to 2. like 3 * 2 * 1 (base and will end the loop).

Answer (score 0):

use factorial function:

```
static long Factorial(long number)
    {
    if( number <= 1 )
        return 1;
    else
        return number * Factorial(number - 1);
    }
```

and then call the function:

```
long result = Factorial(int.Parse(factorialNumberTextBox.Text));
factorialAnswerTextBox.Text = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int numberInt=1 ;

            for (int i = 1; i <= int.Parse(factorialNumberTextBox.Text); i++)
            {

                numberInt = numberInt * i;
            }

            factorialNumberTextBox.Text = numberInt.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
int numberInt = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int answer = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberInt; i++)
        {
            answer = answer * i;
        }

        textBox1.Text = answer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods are implemented: **Recursive** and **Basic** factorial calculation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication50
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        NumberManipulator manipulator = new NumberManipulator();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Factorial Number:");
        int a= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("---Basic Calling--");
        Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} is: {1}" ,a, manipulator.factorial(a));

        Console.WriteLine("--Recursively Calling--");
        Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} is: {1}", a, manipulator.recursively(a));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class NumberManipulator
{
    public int factorial(int num)
    {
        int result=1;
        int b = 1;
        do
        {
            result = result * b;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            b++;
        } while (num >= b);
        return result;
    }

    public int recursively(int num)
    {
        if (num <= 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return recursively(num - 1) * num;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
    int numberFactorial = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int result = numberFactorial;

    for (int i = 1; i < numberFactorial; i++)
    {
        result = result * i;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}",numberFactorial,i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice factorial solution for your nice evening.

```c#
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int fact = 1;
for (int i = num; i > 0; --i)
    fact *= i;
Console.WriteLine(fact);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      string result =   Convert.ToString(GetFactorial(5));
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    internal static int GetFactorial(int factNumber)
    {
        int factorial =1;
        int i = factNumber;            
        while(factNumber>=1)
        {
          factorial = factNumber * factorial;
            factNumber--;
        }
       return  factorial;

    }
```

Comment: You should be aware that [your answer has been flagged for deletion by somebody](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10991115) (not me) - probably because it's a code-only answer. Would you care to explain how your code works, and how it answers the question?

Comment: @WaiHaLee I don't think that's the only reason. This answer is late to the question, there are other answers which are better, the code formatting is a bit messy, and a while-loop is used where a for-loop would be better. In my opinion, it would've been better if this was deleted.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
public int FactorialFunction(int Factorial){
        int Product = Factorial -1;
        for(int Number = Factorial - 1; Number < Factorial; Number++ ) {
            Factorial = Product * Factorial;
            Product--;
        }
        return Factorial;
}
```

Comment: That's a complicated way of writing `if (Factorial == 2) { return 2; } else { return 0; };`.