# How to multiply each number by minus the number by 1 in C#?

Tags: c#, multiplication

I have a number 10, I want to multiply each number by minus the number by 1 it something like:

> 10! = 10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1

Then the result.
How to handle this in C#?

Comment: You want co calculate the [factorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583665/for-loop-to-calculate-factorials).

Comment: `while( mul != 0 ) result *= mul--`or such...

Comment: This is called [Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) in Math. And this Google [search](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=c%23+calculate+factorial) returns 134.000 result. Check it out.

Comment: A tiny optimisation: `while( mul != 1 ) result *= mul--` (since multiplying by 1 isn't necessary)

Comment: And there is a BigInteger.Factorial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common.biginteger.factorial%28v=vs.93%29.aspx). I assume it's in BigInteger and not part of the normal int math lib because even modest arguments' results would overflow.

Comment: A valid answer might be "you handle it in C# like in any other programming language" ;-)

Comment: @PeterSchneider Note that the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` class does *not* have `Factorial()`. The `Solver Foundation` version of `BigInteger` (which does) requires a separate download and installation from standard .Net. - Might be a bit overkill just for a factorial.

Comment: Yes, I followed your link I got it thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple factorial function.  You can use a recursive method:

```
unsigned int Factorial(unsigned int val)
{
    return (1 == val)? 1 : Factorial(val - 1);
}
```

Or an iterative method:

```
unsigned int Factorial(unsigned int val)
{
    unsigned int result = val;
    while(1 < --val)
    {
        result *= val;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that it wont work for large input values because teh factorial will quickly overflow an integer.

Comment: Why `return result -1`?

Comment: @PeterSchneider Because I can't type before I've had a coffe.  :-)  Thanks for pointing that out.  Fixed it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Factorial(50) returns -3258495067890909184

Answer (score -1):

try this -

```
        var res = 1;
        for (int num = 10; num > 0; num--)
            res += res * (num - 1);

        MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
```

Comment: Although what the OP said was a little unclear I'd assume that the example shows what he wants, namely compute the factorial. In that case your one liner is only the first step.

Comment: OP asked clearly how to calculate [factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). The sample says it all.