# Calculating The Factorial of a Number

Tags: c#, factorial

When I enter the number 6 to calculate its factorial, it returns 30 (which is wrong).

Why is my program producing incorrect output?

```
using System;

namespace Scenario1_2
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter, number, fact;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you wish to factorize");
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            fact = number;

            for (counter = number - 1; counter >= 1; counter--)
            {
                fact = fact * counter;

                Console.WriteLine("The number you entered was {0} and it's factorial is {1}", number, fact);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Move your console.writeline and readline outside the loop. That or keep hitting enter until you get the answer.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much, that makes sense!

Comment: try [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/thhGTa)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583665/for-loop-to-calculate-factorials

Answer (score 7):

You look new to programming, or least C#, so just for fun, this will blow your mind:

```
using System;

namespace Scenario1_2
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you wish to factorize");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The number you entered was {0} and it's factorial is {1}", number, Factorial(number));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static int Factorial(int n)
        {
           if (n >= 2) return n * Factorial(n - 1);
           return 1;
        } 
    }
}
```

No loops anywhere, and the function [calls itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

You can also do it like this:

```
using System;

namespace Scenario1_2
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you wish to factorize");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The number you entered was {0} and it's factorial is {1}", number, Factorial(number));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static int Factorial(int n)
        {
           return Enumerable.Range(1, n).Aggregate((i, r) => r * i);
        } 
    }
}
```

Which is all kinds of messed up :)  ...but it does get the significant work down to a single line of code.

Then there's my personal favorite, the infinite enumerable:

```
using System;

namespace Scenario1_2
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you wish to factorize");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The number you entered was {0} and it's factorial is {1}", number, Factorials().Skip(number-1).First());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static IEnumerable<int> Factorials()
        {
            int n = 1, f = 1;
            while (true) yield return f = f * n++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the amazing examples! Studying them gave me some major insight. It actually helped me understand recursion better as well! Can't thank you enough!!

Answer (score 1):

The program is paused waiting for some input. You need to move the second `Console.ReadLine()` out of the loop. And likely the `Console.WriteLine()` unless you want to see each iteration completing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move two lines out from the `for` loop. The modified code look like this.

```
using System;

namespace Scenario1_2
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           int counter, number, fact;

           Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you wish to factorize");
           number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           fact = number;

           for (counter = number - 1; counter >= 1; counter--)
           {
               fact = fact * counter; 
           }
           Console.WriteLine("The number you entered was {0} and it's factorial is {1}", number, fact);
           Console.ReadLine();
        } 
    }
}
```

There are lots of ways to calculate Factorial. You can also do it by creating a recursive function. Google can help you a lot on these basic things.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 4, fact = n;
for (int i = n; i > 1; i--)
{
    fact *= (i - 1);
}
Console.WriteLine(fact);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Although this might be the answer to the question, take some time to also explain why is it so. Remember future users of SO might find this and any bit of context helps.

Answer (score -1):

why are You printing the message inside the loop.put it outside the loop

```
Console.WriteLine("The number you entered was {0} and it's factorial is {1}", number, fact);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
namespace factorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int fact = 1; 
            Console.Write("Enter a number to find factorial:");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
            {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            Console.Write("Factorial of" + n +"is :"+fact);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add an explanation with your answers, it will help others in the future. [answer].

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chapter5ProblemTwelve
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      int number;
      int factor = 1;
      int counter;
      System.out.print("Enter a positive integer to display the factorial number: ");
      number = keyboard.nextInt();
      //If the number entered is less then zero. The program will tell the user to enter a positive number
      if (number <= 0)
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter a postive number and rerun the program again.");
      }
      else
      {
      // Math work preformed if user enters a postive number. Example if user enters 4.
      // 1*1 = 1, 1*2 = 2,1*3 = 3, 1*4 = 4, The program will multiple all the answers together 1*2*3*4 = 24
       for (counter = 1; counter <= number; counter++)
       {
         factor = factor * counter;
       }
       //display 
       System.out.println("The factorial number of " + number + " is: " + factor);  

      }

   }

}
```

Comment: Enter a nonegative integer to display the factorial numbers of the integer: 4
The factorial number of 4 is: 24

Answer (score -2):

```html
using System;

namespace septtwenty
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, number, fact;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter the Number");
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            fact = number;
            for (i = number -1; i>=1; i--)
            {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("\nFactorial of Given Number is: "+fact);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```